# How to scan middle 4 digits from long integers value?

Tags: c++, c

I have long value  of 12 digits as output from an arithmetic operation. So i want only the middle 4 value. for example i got 823954957346 and i only want 5495 to store in a variable. can i do this in C or C++ ?

Comment: do you mean the middle four digits?  Your example isn't in binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
main() {
    unsigned long i = 823954957346;
    printf ("%lu\n", i);
    printf ("%lu\n", i / 10000 % 10000); 
}
```

Output:

```
823954957346
5495
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really talking bits, shift right by 4 bits, then mask the four low bits using bitwise AND.  My C++ is a little rusty, but it's something like:

```
number >> 4 & 15
```

If you're talking digits, divide by 10000 then take number mod 10000, like:

```
number / 10000 % 10000
```

Easy.

Comment: You're welcome, l4zyw0rm!  I suppose the bit solution could also use division and mod e.g. number / 16 % 16.  On your example number, bits 4-7, the second nibble, is 0010 or decimal 2.